# Linux: want app to restart itself after COMPLETELY shutting down

Tags: linux, process, exec, fork

I want my app to shut itself down cleanly and have itself be restarted. "Cleanly" means including the compiler-generated code that runs when main() returns (eg destructors on globals, atexit() etc).

Is the correct method to have a parent process that runs continuously, launching the main app as a child process and listening for its termination before launching another one?

Or is there possibly a way for the current app process to run exec() with a fresh image AFTER all the shutdown code has executed?
Thanks

Comment: What is your application doing? Why do you ask? Why exactly does it need to restart like you say? Why can't you have a wrapping shell script doing the necessary work?

Comment: BTW, an application does not always end cleanly. your user could send the `SIGKILL` signal.... or simply the computer could have been powered off at the worst moment.

Comment: Not an answer, as I can't test this right now, but you could probably fork a child, have it wait for the parent to exit (e.g. waiting for a `flock` to be released), then have it `exec` itself.